# HTML 5 buttons, drop a button 1px on active, messed up,affects more than 1 button, how to fix it?

Tags: css, html

Well I have this code which is fairly simple and should set margin-top of HTML 5's button element to 1px when it is active ( mouse clicked on it). But what I get is a messed up layout, because the button does what it should do only it does it for both of the buttons which are right next to each other. Can you tell me what is causing this error to occur?

Here is a sample HTML code (because i cant just link to jsfiddle), but the link to jsfiddle is right at the bottom

```
<header id="main_header"> <!-- this is your header with logo, menu, login and get started now buttons -->
    <div id="header_accent"></div> <!-- small accent image, barely seen on top of the page -->
    <div id="header_holder"> <!-- this guy centers the header to the middle of the page's width -->
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="ssl8.com" id="logo"/> <!-- logo image -->
        <div id="nav_holder"> <!-- positions the navigation and buttons -->
            <nav>
                <ul> <!-- navigation -->
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">prices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="login">login</button> <!-- login button -->
            <button class="getStartedNow">Get started now</button> <!-- get started now button -->
        </div>
        <div id="header_shadow"></div> <!-- holds the background shadow for the header (in CSS file) -->
    </div>
</header> <!-- END of header -->
```

Here is jsfiddle.Ignore missing pictures etc, just click on the orange button and you will see what i am talking about.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfwA/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/emfwA/16/

**What I Changed**

1. You had the `opacity`, `box-shadow`, `transitions`, and `border-radius` set for the buttons set on both buttons, which is redundant. I changed it so that it would apply to all buttons
2. Browser prefixes are not needed for `box-shadow` or `border-radius`
3. For your login button, you forgot the period before your login class, so the css was trying to find a element named login, which doesn't exist
4. Removed the active and hover from both elements and set a generic `active` and `hover` pseudo element
5. Added position relative to each button
6. On active, the button will be given a property of `top: 1px`
7. Changed the size of the header to `min-width:100%` so that the line will go all the way across

The main problem was coming from the fact that your buttons were set at a position of static, so by applying a `margin-top` of `1px`, you were shifting the entire top down. By setting a position of relative, you can add properties such as `top` or `left` and it will move the element in that direction while still keeping the space of the element in the same position

Comment: Didnt know that i can use top,bottom,left and right with relative positioning, thought it is only for absolute positions :) Thanks, I learn something new every day :)

Comment: Good. If you didn't know, absolute takes the element out of the normal flow, while relative keeps it in the same spot

Comment: About beeing redundant. I know, but the designer made different modifications of buttons and even though they all use the sam style, opacity changes from button to button :/ You are right about box-shadow, transitions and border radius though :)

Comment: well you could add a class to the button that you could use for different buttons. You don't want to have the same styling for 2 buttons in different places. you could do something like
`.getStartedNow, .login{
    /*Put same content here*/
}`

Answer (score 1):

I would set the `nav_holder` and `getStartedNow` classes to `position:relative` and then use `top:1px` to move it down the one pixel. That seems to fix the issue.

```
button.getStartedNow:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

I think the previous problem was caused by the way margins work but I don't know it well enough to speak to that.

You would also want to do this with the `login` button to get the same effect there.

Comment: Hm, that doesnt fix the problem, same happens, but thank you for trying :)

Comment: @Novica89 It appears to be working in this updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LpX2h/.

Comment: Gj man it does :) I used margin-top:1px instad of just top:1px. Sorry :) Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Add position: relative to the .getStartedNow class, and change the active snippet to:

```
button.getStartedNow:active {
 bottom: -1px;
}
```

Here a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/emfwA/17/ ..